# mod_rewrite multiple directories to a php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(dir1|dir2|dir3)/(.*)$ /targetfile.php [R,L]
```

`http://www.somesite.com/dir1` -> `http://www.somesite.com/targetfile.php`
`http://www.somesite.com/dir2` -> `http://www.somesite.com/targetfile.php`
`http://www.somesite.com/dir3` -> `http://www.somesite.com/targetfile.php`

From what I've seen online, this should work. Unfortunately, it wont. Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this in a .htaccess file, remove the leading slash from the pattern. And to match only full path segments, you have to alter the expression a little bit.

So try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(dir1|dir2|dir3)(/|$) targetfile.php [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the forward slashes are necessary, unless you want to restrict it to requiring the trailing slash after "dir1."

Try:
    RewriteRule ^(dir1|dir2|dir3)$ targetfile.php [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the regular expression mandates a slash after the directory name (e.g. /dir1/), but in the example the last slash is omitted (http://www.somesite.com/dir1 does not have trailing slash).

I think you could try just with

```
RewriteRule ^/(dir[1-3]) /targetfile.php [R,L]
```